# Where was the furthest extent of Arabian trade explorations?

Tags: middle-ages, trade, arabia, exploration

Traders from Arabia travelled to and traded with [Roman and Asian empires](http://www.metmuseum.org/toah/hd/ince/hd_ince.htm) and [this Nabataean Sea Merchants article](http://nabataea.net/who1a.html).  How far did Arabian traders travel - where was the furthest extent of their expeditions, particularly in Asia (or maybe Australia)?

Comment: What centuries are you asking about?

Comment: Am looking at around the 10th to 15th centuries

Comment: It is often though that the legend of the *roc* was inspired by the sight of ostrich and emu, due to their resemblance to eagle chicks in appearance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a full answer, but if you're interested by medieval Arabic travels, the unavoidable reference is [Ibn Baṭūṭah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Battuta). In his Rihla, he describes three travels he made during the 14<sup>th</sup> century :

1. from Tangiers to middle-East, with a travel along the East coast of Africa, down to Zanbar and Kilwa. ([map here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Battuta#Itinerary_1325.E2.80.931332))
2. from Mecca to Beijing, and back, through Eastern Europe, Central Asia, India and South-East Asia. From the way you phrase your question, it's probably the travel which interest you more. ([map here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Battuta#Itinerary_1332.E2.80.931346) and below)
3. from Mecca to the [Mali Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mali_Empire) and back. ([map here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Battuta#Itinerary_1349.E2.80.931354))

[image: Ibn Battuta's travel to Asia]

This text has been translated in many languages, so you probably can find a version in your preferred language. There is a [French translation in *la Pléïade*](http://www.la-pleiade.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Bibliotheque-de-la-Pleiade/Voyageurs-arabes), and a 19<sup>th</sup> French translation freely downloadable at the [Université du Québec à Chicoutimi](http://classiques.uqac.ca/classiques/civilisation_arabe/civilisation_arabe_index.html); I haven't found (yet) an English translation available on the web.

He mainly used the commercial routes, but he probably didn't to "the furthest extent of [Arabic] expeditions. According to the wikipedia page on [spice trade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice_trade#Arab_trade_and_medieval_Europe), the route went as far East as [Molucca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molucca).

Comment: Hi Frederic, I am sure that you can find some useful references for Arabic travelers in Eastern Africa, i.e. Somalia, Kenya and South as far as Zanzibar and Madagascar (at least). I have remembrance of reading about Arabic merchant trading with these people when I studied Hanno the Navigator. +1 Anyways

Comment: By the way, traveling as far east as Khanbalik (=Beijing) was already possible Eastern Christians in the Middle Ages, who knew China as "Tzinitza". In fact, it was a Christian Bishop that helped translating the Buddhist sacred texts into Chinese.

Comment: So you're saying that Ibn Batutah is a "canonical" reference point for this issue? +1

Comment: This reference, particularly the map has answered one of the main queries I had in my initial question - about the outside possibility of visits to the Australian mainland, I can see how very unlikely this was.

Comment: @TomAu I'm not qualified to say whether Ibn Battuta is a canonical reference point on the maximal extension of the Arabic trade route networks. All I know is that his travels are a classic of the Arab travel literature.