# How did Muslim traders raise investments given Islam's prohibition of usury?

Tags: middle-ages, economy, islam, trade, caliphate

During early caliphate era (7th-13th century), Muslim traders dominated trade in Indian Ocean and the Mediterranean (see [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/where-was-the-furthest-extent-of-arabian-trade-explorations) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_trade#Muslim_period) for example). I think Islam's [prohibition of interest or usury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riba) must have made raising investment difficult, why would people lend money for merchants to buy their goods if they can't get interest from it?

How did the merchants raise investments, like for buying goods, ships, funding sailors and employees? Were Muslim traders disadvantaged compared to their competitors due to the usury  prohibition, and how did they manage to compensate this disadvantage?

Comment: DAvid Graeber went into this in Debt: the first 5000 years, though I don't recall exactly how it was supposed to work.

Comment: why borrow money when you can steal it with impunity from the infidels because your holy books says you can?

Comment: @jwenting by steal, you mean rob, like a pirate? But you need ships and crew for that, meaning you need initial investment..

Comment: Also, the [Indian ocean trade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_trade) was mostly peaceful, before the arrival of the Europeans

Comment: There's profit sharing. There's also *hibah*, which means giving a reward. Someone could have an informal agreement that if they borrow $1k, they'll pay back $1k and a 'hibah' of maybe $100. In effect, it gives similar returns to interest, but is not enforced.

Comment: @jwenting are you saying that it is the common way for merchants in this era to raise funds for their venture? That's completely new to me

Answer (score 22):

Usually islamic banks give loans for a share in the income of the business project as opposed to fixed percent of the loan sum (see [*mudarabah*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_banking#Mudarabah))

The consumer loans may utilize another scheme: the bank buys, for example, a car and it becomes the bank's property, then you use this car and slowly re-buy it from the bank for greater money. Once you finished, the car becomes yours.

Comment: +1 - This **is** the correct answer and should be accepted - it is easily verifiable. BTW, religious Jews, who also abide by the same prohibition, use exactly the same workarounds.

Comment: Yeah, but references would be nice.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - true. But I believe this is current practice (I **know** it is in the Jewish world), and it sounds like Anixx is speaking from personal knowledge and experience. Perhaps Anixx can attest to this. If so, I would consider that a primary source, with no further references necessary.

Comment: @Vector Sorry, Anixx is not a reliable source. I have no doubt to the correctness of the answer, but I'm not voting it up unless we get some reliable sources.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - if so I agree that some verification is necessary.

Comment: It sounds very logical but the question is how "did" they, not how "can" they. That is why we need sources. The theory is very reasonable though.

Comment: In fact, I know this is how Islamic banks today lend money (I added a wikipedia link), but my question is how about 7th-13th century, when there were no banks? How do we know that they also used these methods?

Comment: both schemes sound like interest carrying loans to me...

Comment: @jwenting Shhh......

Comment: You might have confused **Mudarabah** with **Murabahah**. Mudarabah is a concept where one person provides the money, the other person provides the workload and know how. Murabahah is arguably usury (as I've questioned on Islam SE: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7887/why-is-murabaha-not-considered-riba )

Comment: @Fitri: It was no difference before you got banks, it was just individuals who did what banks do instead.

Comment: @LennartRegebro probably, but while we can probably take Anixx's word when he observe banks today do these practices (I know they do), I think we need reference to claim that individuals ~13 centuries ago also did the same trick

Comment: I think this muzarabbah or Islamic Banking is a new concept which has been formed in this century when banking became essential to any nation. Is there any backing or example of it pre-Colonial era times?

Answer (score 8):

I upvoted Anixx's answer but I would still like to add mine to expand on it in a more middle ages context. **Credit for purposes of trade was** **absolutely legal**. In the work [Credit as a means of investement in medieval Islamic trade](https://www.jstor.org/stable/597719?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) we encounter the following:

> The earliest Muslim legal sources
> now justify the assertion that already in the late
> eighth century, and possibly earlier, credit arrangements of various types constituted an important feature of both trade and industry.

This was justified on interpretations of the Quran. In the source mentioned above there are several quoted from Muslim scholars describing credit transactions. The first quote comes from [Muhammad al-Shaybani's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Shaybani) " Book of Partnership ", the earliest Hanafi code, and describes *a provision entitling each of
the parties to a partnership to buy and sell on
credit. Furthermore, unless otherwise
stipulated, neither partner requires the express
permission of his colleague for the sale on credit
of any of their joint property*:

> This is (the instrument) upon which Fuhlan the son of
> Fuhlan and Fuhlan the son of Fulan have entered into
> a partnership. **They entered the partnership** in a  Godfearing manner and with mutual fidelity. They
> have become partners in all things, acquisitions,
> and skills, in **a total investment partnership**. They
> may **sell for cash or credit**, and they may **buy for
> cash or credit**; and each of them may operate in
> these matters according to judgment. Their capital
> is such and such, belonging equally to both of them,
> and all of it is in their possession. Whatever
> benefit God, the Exalted, grants them is to be shared
> equally between them; whatever loss or setback
> overtakes them is to be borne by them in equal
> shares. They have entered into a partnership on
> this basis in the month so and so of the year so
> and so.

Another important quote, from the same source, is that from [Al-Sarakhsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Sarakhsi) according to whom **credit dealings were almost indispensable to successful and profitable trading**. To quote:

> We hold that **selling for credit is part of the practice of merchants, and that it is the most conducive
> means for the achievement of the investor's goal
> which is profit**. And in most cases, profit can only
> be achieved by selling for credit and not selling
> for cash...  **Proof that selling for credit is an absolute feature
> of trade is found in His statement**, may He be
> exalted, "unless it be local trade that ye are conducting amongst you." This shows that trade
> can also be long distant, and this latter type of
> trade cannot come about except by selling on
> credit.

Answer (score 3):

> When the law prohibits interest altogether, it does not prevent it.
>   Many people must borrow, and nobody will lend without such a
>   consideration for the use of their money as is suitable, not only to
>   what can be made by the use of it, but to the difficulty and danger of
>   evading the law. The high rate of interest among all Mahometan nations
>   is accounted for by Mr. Montesqieu, not from their poverty, but partly
>   from this, and partly from the difficulty of recovering the money.
>
> *["The Wealth of Nations" - Adam Smith]*

It was not so much a question of being able to raise investments, but of being able to do so at an interest rate sustainable for business. Law, be it religious or not, increases artificially the interest rate, thus seriously crippling economic life, but it never effectively eradicates it.

Comment: your conclusion does not follow from the quote. Smith quotes Montesque where the latter states that poverty leads to a high risk of non-recovery of loans which in turn leads to needing high interest rates to cover that risk. That has nothing to do with legal or religious climate, it's pure economics and equally valid in all legal systems.

Comment: I was not drawing a conclusion from the quote. If one sentence follows another, it doesn't mean they form a reasoning.